# How do I get user email using Facebook Graph API in GAE Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API on Google App Engine. I was able to fetch all the basic info from an user. However when I tried to fetch any user info that requires permission, email for exemple, it always appears as None. I've followed the whole tutorial available at the [developers blog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web).

Here's my code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)


class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """Provides access to the active Facebook user in self.current_user

    The property is lazy-loaded on first access, using the cookie saved
    by the Facebook JavaScript SDK to determine the user ID of the active
    user. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for
    more information.
    """
    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
                self.request.cookies, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
            if cookie:
                # Store a local instance of the user data so we don't need
                # a round-trip to Facebook on every request
                user = User.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                if not user:
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = User(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                                id=str(profile["id"]),
                                name=profile["name"],
                                email=profile["email"],
                                profile_url=profile["link"],
                                access_token=cookie["access_token"])
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                self._current_user = user
        return self._current_user
```

And here is the template/HTML:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email"></fb:login-button>

{% if current_user %}
  <p><a href="{{ current_user.profile_url }}"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{ current_user.id }}/picture?type=square"/></a></p>
  <p>Hello, {{ current_user.name|escape }}</p>
  <p>email: {{ current_user.email }} </p>
{% endif %}
```

Is there something wrong? Is there other way to get user email?

Comment: Try adding some debug output of the profile you get from FB and see if the email is there.  When the FB authorization dialog comes up, does it include email permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just gave up using [facebook.py](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.py) and [facebookoauth.py](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py) and made my own OAuth 2 client using urlfetch. See ['Authenticating Users in a Web Application'](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) in Facebook docs.

Also, I put `scope='email'` in requests to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?` and `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?`.

Answer (score 1):

Email is written on User creation. Maybe you are trying to access users that were created when you didn't have email permission, therefore the written email was None. Does the problem appear also for new User object?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct so I would assume that you don't have the correct extended permissions. You must ask for the "email" extended permission if you are going to try to get the email address. You can find the list of extended permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions). You must ask for these permissions before you can read these properties using the Graph API.

Comment: He has perms="email" in the login button tag.  That should prompt for the permission.